# Does the product $\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+\frac{|x_i|^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right)$ converges to $e$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have been reviewing college calculus and forgot this result.

> Let $(x_i)$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers. Does the product
> $$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+\frac{|x_i|^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right)$$
> converges to $e$?

It seems that if $(|x_i|)$ is bounded with $\delta \leq |x_i| \leq M$ for all $i\in \mathbb N$, where $\delta>0$, then
$$\left(1+\frac{\delta^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right)^n \leq \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+\frac{|x_i|^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right) \leq \left(1+\frac{M^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right)^n.$$
Hence both bounds tend to $e$. But here I'm assuming, for a constant $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$,
$$\left(1+\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right)^n\rightarrow e,$$
since $a^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow 1$.
Is that correct?

Comment: It’s a bit odd to write it this way, since you could write it the terms $1+\frac{y_i}n$ where $\{y_i\}$ is a positive real sequence, ($y_i=|x_i|.$)

Comment: If all $|x_i|\leq 1$ then it seems you can use dominated convergence theorem. Probably can do the same if all $|x_i|\geq 1.$ But for mixes, not sure.

Comment: If $x_i = i^i$ the product diverges, so unless there's more conditions on $x_i$ there's no much we can say about the convergence of the product.

Comment: @jjagmath Would it help to restrict to reals? It seems if $\delta < |x_i| \leq M$ being bounded with a positive lower bound guarantees converging to $e$. But can it be true more generally?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Does it really need that high level material to prove?

Comment: Don’t know, that was just the first thing that came to mind. @user760

Comment: I have asked a more general question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503017/what-are-the-possible-values-of-prod-i-1n-1-y-i-frac-1n-n)

Answer (score 3):

(1) You are more or less correct when $|x_i|$ are bounded by $\delta$ and $M$. To make it rigorous, for any $\epsilon>0$, let $n$ be large (depending on $\epsilon, \delta, M$ so that
$$ \delta^{1/n} > 1-\epsilon, \ \ \ M^{1/n} < 1+\epsilon.$$

Write

$$ b_n = \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+\frac{|x_i|^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right).$$

Then

$$\tag{1} \left( 1+ \frac{1-\epsilon}{n}\right)^n <b_n < \left( 1+ \frac{1-\epsilon}{n}\right)^n .$$
Hence

$$ e^{1-\epsilon} \le \liminf b_n \le \limsup b_n \le e^{1+\epsilon}.$$

Since $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary and $e^x$ is continuous,

$$ e = \liminf b_n=  \limsup b_n$$

and thus limit exists.

(2) In general if there is no bound on $|x_i|$, there might not be a limit. For example, let $x_i = (i^2)^i$. Then

$$ b_n \ge 1 + \frac{|x_n|^{1/n}}{n} = 1 + n$$

and thus $(b_n)$ is unbounded.

(3) The upper and lower bound of $(x_i)$ can be relaxed to something like
$$ c i^{-\alpha}<|x_i| < Ci^\beta$$
for some $c, C, \alpha ,\beta>0$. Since this implies that for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $i \ge n$,
$$ c^{1/n} (n^{1/n})^\alpha < |x_i|^{1/n} < C^{1/n} (n^{1/n})^\alpha.$$
Since both $c^{1/n}, C^{1/n}$ and $n^{1/n}$ converges to $1$ as $n\to \infty$, for all $\epsilon >0$ there is $N\in \mathbb N$ depending on $c, C, \alpha, \beta$ such that
$$ 1-\epsilon < |x_i|^{1/n} < 1+\epsilon$$
for all $n\ge N$ and $i \ge N$. This implies (1) again for $n\ge N$ and thus the limit of $(b_n)$ is again $e$.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems possible the upper bound can be relaxed to be increasing with $n$ somehow

Comment: @user760 Yes (see the edit). In general, my guess is that you can choose $x_i$ so that the infinite product converges to any real number.