# What are the possible values of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1+ y_i^{\frac 1n}/n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

For any sequence $(y_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ of positive real numbers, let $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be another sequence defined by
$$X_n = \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+\frac{y_i^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right).$$
It is clear that $X_n >1$ for all $n$.

> Question: For any $c\ge 1$, can one find a sequence $(y_i)$ of positive real numbers such that $\left(X_n\right)$ converges to $c$ as $n\to \infty$?

In an answer to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502631/does-the-product-prod-i-1n-left1-fracx-i-frac1nn-right-co), it is shown that if $y_i, y_i^{-1}$ grows slower than polynomials, then the limit of $(X_n)$ is always $e$. There are also simple examples $\left(y_i = \left(i^2\right)^i\right)$ which shows that $(X_n)$ might be unbounded.

Some remarks:

- One can find $(y_i)$ such that $(X_n)$ is bounded, but has no limit (this can be done by choosing $y_i$ to be $1$ most of the time, and a huge number once in a while),
- Changing finitely many members of $(y_i)$ do not alter the limit of $(X_n)$.
- Think of $(y_i)$ as a function $y: \mathbb N \to (0,\infty)$. Then $f_n : \mathbb N \to (0,\infty)$ defined by $f_n(i) = y_i^{1/n}$ is a sequence of functions which converges pointwisely to the constant function $1$. If the convergence is uniform, then limit of $(X_n)$ exists, but again the limit is $e$.

Comment: I inserted a $\lim$ in the question title. If you don't agree that matches the intent, you can edit again.

Comment: My answer was incorrect, and $(X_n)$ doesn't actually need to be increasing.

Comment: It seems to be true that any $c\ge1$ is possible by taking $y_i$ of the form $y_i=A^i$ for some $A\ge1$. Indeed, numerically looking at examples with $y_i=A^i$ leads me to conjecture that these limits equal $e^{(A-1)/\log A}$. The analogous sum $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(A^i)^{1/n}}n$ is easy to evaluate; assuming one can prove that the corresponding $X_n$ converge at all, one should be able to use the intermediate value theorem and inequalities like $X_n \le e^{S_n}$ to answer the OP's qualitative question in the affirmative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer in largest is inspired by the insightful comments and answers of users at the post. I think that a small detail is missing so I will be proving it in the answer. Let $y_i = A^i$ with $A>0$,

\begin{align}
\log X_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left(1 + \frac1n A^{\frac kn}\right)
\end{align}

Using the fact that for $u \in (0, 1)$, $u - \frac{u^2}{2} \le \log (1+u) \le u$, Then for $n > 1+A^2$ and $1\le k\le n$, $\frac{1}{n} A^{\frac kn} \le \frac{1+A^{2}}{n} < 1$ and

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac1n A^{\frac kn} - \frac12 \left(\frac 1n A^{\frac {k}n}\right)^2 \right)\le \log & X_n \le \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac1n A^{\frac kn}\\
\implies \quad \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n A^{\frac{k}{n}} - \frac{1+A^2}{2n} \le \log & X_n \le \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n A^{\frac kn} 
\end{align}

By tending $n\to \infty$, you have that:

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} X_n &= e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log X_n}\\
&= e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n A^{\frac{k}{n}}}\\
&= e^{\int_0^1 A^x\mathrm d x} = e^{\frac{A-1}{\log A}}
\end{align}

Since $A \to \frac{A-1}{\log A}$ sends $(0, \infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$, then the result that you are looking for is immediate.

Answer (score 2):

Assume all functions of the form
$$
f(t)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}c_ke^{p_kt}.\tag 1
$$
Assume also that for all $k,n\in\textbf{N}$, we have
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^n=f\left(\frac{n}{k}\right).\tag 2
$$
Then set
$$
S:=\prod^{n}_{k=1}\left(1+\frac{f(k)^{1/n}}{n}\right).
$$
We have
$$
\log S=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=-\sum^{n}_{k=1}\sum^{\infty}_{l=1}\frac{(-1)^l}{ln^l}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^l=
$$
$$
=-\sum^{\infty}_{l=1}\frac{(-1)^l}{ln^{l-1}}\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{k=1}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^l\approx-\sum^{\infty}_{l=1}\frac{(-1)^l}{ln^{l-1}}\int^{1}_{0}f(t)^ldt=
$$
$$
=\int^{1}_{0}n\log\left(\frac{n+f(t)}{n}\right)dt.
$$
Hence when $n\rightarrow \infty$, then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod^{n}_{k=1}\left(1+\frac{f(k)^{1/n}}{n}\right)=\exp\left(\int^{1}_{0}f(t)dt\right).\tag 3
$$
As an example we can take $f(t)=2^t$.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a **non-answer** (although too long for a comment) and is in its largest part the work of Greg Martin (for their insightful comment) as well as Sangchul Lee and Carl Schildkraut for their answer to [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503847/does-lim-n-to-infty-sum-i-1n-ai-n1-ai-n-0-for-any-a-ge-1?noredirect=1#comment9453531_4503847).

---

If the limit
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{i=1}^n\left( 1  + \frac{A^{i/n}}{n}\right)$$
can be proven to exist for any $A\ge 0$, then the answer is in the affirmative, and would easily follow from the fact that the function
$$f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}:A\mapsto \lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{i=1}^n\left( 1 + \frac{A^{(i/n)}}{n}\right) \tag{1}$$
is monotonically increasing and has $(1, \infty)$ as range (proven at the end of the post). In particular, for any $c\ge 1$ we may find $A\in (0,\infty)$ such that the sequence $\{ A^i\}$ gives the desired result.

---

**Regarding whether the limit in $(1)$ exists:**
letting $b_i = (A^{i/n})/n$, the inequality
$$1+\sum_{i=1}^nb_i \le \prod_{i=1}^n\left( 1 + b_i\right)\le \exp \left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)\tag{2}$$
should draw our attention to the series $\sum b_i$. Observe that, letting $s_n = \sum_i^n y_i^{1/n}$, we get
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^nb_i = & \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nA^{i/n}\\
= & \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{s_n}{n}\\
= & \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{s_{n+1}-s_n}{(n+1)-n} \ \ (\text{by the Stolz-Cesàro Theorem})\\
= & \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(A + \sum_{i=1}^n \left(A^{i/(n+1)}-A^{i/n}\right)\right)\\
= & \frac{A-1}{\log A} \ \ (\text{by Sangchul Lee's/Carl Schidkraut's answer)}
\end{split}
Therefore $(2)$ becomes
$$1+\frac{A-1}{\log A} \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n\left( 1 + b_i\right) \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n\left( 1 + b_i\right) \le \exp \left(\frac{A-1}{\log A}\right).$$
Furthermore, the equation
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+b_i\right) = \exp \left( \sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+b_i)\right)$$
implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod (1+b_i)$ exists if and only if so does $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum \log(1+b_i)$.

---

The fact that **the range of $f$ is $(1,\infty)$** follows from first inequality in $(2)$ together with the facts that $f(0)=1$ and that $f$ is is monotone.

Comment: Nice answer. Can you say something about why limit in (1) exists?

Comment: I thought the limit of the product would exist if and only if so did the limit of the series. Now I realize that, since the $b_i$ depend also on $n$, that may not follow. I'll edit the post so as to make it clear it is a non-answer.

Comment: The limit exists. You were very close to prove it, however you did not use the right inequality for $\prod \left(1+b_i\right)$