# Does $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n (A^{i/(n+1)}-A^{i/n}) = 0$ for any $A\ge 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I conjecture that the following limit
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n (A^{i/(n+1)}-A^{i/n})$$
is zero for any $A\ge 1$, but I cannot come up with a proof nor a counterexample, and I was wondering if someone else could.

---

For some context, I became interested in the limit after reading Greg Martin's comment in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503017/what-are-the-possible-values-of-lim-limits-n-to-infty-prod-i-1n-1-y-i).

Comment: What about $A=1$?

Comment: @csch2 You are right, I corrected the question.

Comment: Is it $A\geqslant0 \: or\: 1$? should I follow the description or the title?

Comment: @VitalsBat The title. I'll correct the description.

Comment: Try  $\frac{i}{n+1}=\frac{i}{n}-\frac{i}{n(n+1)}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A > 0$. By the mean value theorem, for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we have

$$ A^{\frac{i}{n+1}} - A^{\frac{i}{n}} = -\frac{i}{n(n+1)}A^{x_i} \log A $$

for some $x_i \in (\frac{i}{n+1}, \frac{i}{n}) \subseteq [\frac{i}{n+1}, \frac{i+1}{n+1}]$. So,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (A^{\frac{i}{n+1}} - A^{\frac{i}{n}})
= -\frac{n+1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n+1} A^{x_i}(\log A) \frac{1}{n+1}  $$

Regarding the last sum as a Riemann sum, it therefore follows that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (A^{\frac{i}{n+1}} - A^{\frac{i}{n}})
= -\int_{0}^{1} x A^x \log A \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{A - 1}{\log A} - A. $$

(Here, we regard $\frac{A - 1}{\log A} = 1$ if $A = 1$.)

Answer (score 3):

No; in fact, it is always negative for $A>1$. We explicitly evaluate the limit. One has
$$A^{\frac{i}{n+1}}-A^{\frac in}=A^{\frac in}\left(A^{-\frac{i}{n(n+1)}}-1\right)=A^{\frac in}\left(e^{\frac{-i\log A}{n(n+1)}}-1\right).$$
Note that $1+x\leq e^x\leq 1+x+x^2$ for $x\leq 0$, so as long as $n\geq \log A$,
$$\left|\left(A^{\frac{i}{n+1}}-A^{\frac in}\right)-A^{\frac in}\left(-\frac{i\log A}{n(n+1)}\right)\right|\leq A^{\frac in}\frac{i^2\log^2A}{n^2(n+1)^2}.$$
This means that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(A^{\frac{i}{n+1}}-A^{\frac in}\right)\text{ and }-\sum_{i=1}^nA^{\frac in}\frac{i\log A}{n(n+1)}$$
differ by at most
$$\sum_{i=1}^n A^{\frac in}\frac{i^2\log^2A}{n^2(n+1)^2}\leq \frac{A\log^2 A}{n^2(n+1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^n n^2=O\left(\frac 1n\right)$$
for large $n$, and so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(A^{\frac{i}{n+1}}-A^{\frac in}\right)=-\log A\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac inA^{i/n}.$$
The limit can be interpreted as a Riemann sum for the function $xA^x$, and so the desired expression is
$$-\log A\int_0^1 xA^xdx=-\frac{1+A\log A-A}{\log A}=-A+\frac{A-1}{\log A}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can obtain much more than the limit itself

$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nA^{\frac{i}{n+1}} - A^{\frac{i}{n}} =-\frac{A-1}{A^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}+\frac{A-1}{A^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-1}-A$$
Assuming $A>1$ and using series expansions
$$S_n=\frac{A-1}{\log (A)}-A-\frac{(A-1) \log (A)}{12 n^2}\Bigg[1-\frac 1n +\frac{20-\log ^2(A)}{20 n^2}+\frac{\log ^2(A)-10}{10 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\Bigg]$$

Trying for $A=e$, the truncated series leads to
$$S_{10}=-\frac{5995457+4543 e}{6000000}=  \color{red}{-1.001301}03$$ while, converted to decimals, the exact value is $\color{red}{-1.00130114}$

Comment: (+1) Hi! I have a question unrelated to the contexts of your answer. The answer looks correct. I’ve noticed that you’re very good at expanding an expression in series form. I’m just curious, how did you get the expansions? By pure hand-computation, or with the help of a software? Sometimes, the expansions are not easy to calculate explicitly, especially the cases where the coefficients are very large. I don’t mean anything bad. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Feng. To tell you the truth : first, I felt in love with Taylor (series) and Padé (approximants) some 64+ years ago. Second : I am blind which makes that I developed an extravagant memory over time and, being old, I want to exercise it as much as I can.  For this specific problem, up to $O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ just mental calculations. For the next terms, I used a CAS. Does this answer the question ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Incredible! I'm stunned by your stories! It reminds me of Leonhard Euler! I thought you're just very good at computing these things by *hand*. But I was totally wrong! You did them on your mind! How can I express my admiration for you! Thanks for your nice reply, which has answered all my questions. I feel very lucky to talk with you. Take care of yourself!

Comment: @Feng. Are you kidding the old man ? Just a small part of things are mentally done. Then, as everybody, CAS. Cheers and thanks.